# How to customize error schema in FastApi and Pydantic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I make FastAPI application I face to structural problem.
For example, let's say there is exist this simple application

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Header
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = FastAPI()


class PydanticSchema(BaseModel):
    test_int: int = Field(..., ge=0)


class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status_code, msg):
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.msg = msg


@app.exception_handler(CustomException)
async def handle_custom_exception(request, exc: CustomException):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=exc.status_code, content={"error": exc.msg}
    )


@app.post("/")
def index(
    some_form: PydanticSchema,
    some_header: str = Header("", alias="X-Header", max_length=3),
):
    is_special_case = some_form.test_int == 42
    if is_special_case:
        raise CustomException(418, "Very special case")
    return "ok"
```

And here is the problem.
I have THREE independent producers of errors: My manual raise, Pydantic Model, FastApi.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = TestClient(app)
    cases = (
        ({"X-Header": "abc"}, {"test_int": 0}),
        ({"X-Header": "abcdef"}, {"test_int": 0}),
        ({"X-Header": "abc"}, {"test_int": -1}),
        ({"X-Header": "abc"}, {"test_int": 42}),
    )
    for case in cases:
        r = client.post("/", headers=case[0], json=case[1])
        print(f"#####\n{case=}:\n{r.status_code=}\n{r.text=}")
```

**My goal** is to have consistent error responses
So I have to add exception handler for my `CustomException`,
I have to add `error_msg_templates` to PydanticModel.Config
I have to add incredibly stupid handler for FastApi exception and Pydantic exception to reformat them into my custom response. Becasuse fastapi overrides custom messages from pydantic templates.
Like so:

```py
# ---snip---
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError

# ---snip---
class PydanticSchema(BaseModel):
    test_int: int = Field(..., ge=0)

    class Config:
        error_msg_templates = {"value_error.number.not_ge": "Custom GE error"}

# ---snip---
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def fastapi_error_handler(request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    errors = exc.errors()
    error_wrapper = exc.raw_errors[0]
    validation_error = error_wrapper.exc
    from pydantic import error_wrappers as ew
    if isinstance(validation_error, ew.ValidationError):
        errors = validation_error.errors()
    
    first_error = errors[0]
    msg = first_error.get("msg")
    # [!] Demonstration
    etype = first_error.get("type")
    if etype == "value_error.any_str.max_length":
        msg = "Custom MAX length error"
    return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content={"error": msg})

# ---snip---
```

It is unmaintainable! But custom error message is required -  I can not rely ond default pydantic\fastapi error response schemas.

Does anyone one faced to this problem and have solved it gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

Why not FastAPI's Exception_handler argument? You can view the status code of the response when this error occurs, then add an exception handler. Exception handlers have access to the Request & Exception objects, which are the request that caused the exception, and the exception raised, respectively.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError

def val_err(request: Request, exception: Exception):
    if not isinstance(exception, RequestValidationError):
        return
    errors = exc.errors()
    error_wrapper = exc.raw_errors[0]
    validation_error = error_wrapper.exc
    from pydantic import error_wrappers as ew
    if isinstance(validation_error, ew.ValidationError):
        errors = validation_error.errors()
    
    first_error = errors[0]
    msg = first_error.get("msg")
    # [!] Demonstration
    etype = first_error.get("type")
    if etype == "value_error.any_str.max_length":
        msg = "Custom MAX length error"
    return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content={"error": msg})
    

exception_handlers = {422: val_err}
app = FastAPI(exception_handlers=exception_handlers)
```

You can refer to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800133/how-to-make-a-custom-404-page/71818874#71818874) which dissects the code and explains it in a bit more detail.